# Изменение внешнего вида иконок на карте

Tags: карты, яндекс-карты, icon, иконки

См. изображение. Хочу заменить "полиция", "мойка" и т.п. на свои изображения. Ну или хотя бы увеличить существующие иконки.
[image: Яндекс карта]

Comment: Маркеры на карте менять нельзя - они часть подложки и поставляются as is в дизайне Яндекса

Answer (score 0):

На карту можно добавить метку со своим изображение.
Рискну предположить, что бы изменить изображение тех меток которые уже есть, нужно работать в Яндексе :)
Возможно я не прав... и есть какое-либо толковое решение.
Могу предложить следующий вариант решения вашей проблемы: добавить свои метки со своим иозображением.
К примеру:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
      zoom: 9
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),

    // Создаём макет содержимого.
    MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    ),

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
      hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
      balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
    }, {
      // Опции.
      // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
      iconLayout: 'default#image',
      // Своё изображение иконки метки.
      iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif',
      // Размеры метки.
      iconImageSize: [30, 42],
      // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
      // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
      iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    }),

    myPlacemarkWithContent = new ymaps.Placemark([55.661574, 37.573856], {
      hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки с контентом',
      balloonContent: 'А эта — новогодняя',
      iconContent: '12'
    }, {
      // Опции.
      // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
      iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
      // Своё изображение иконки метки.
      iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/ball.png',
      // Размеры метки.
      iconImageSize: [48, 48],
      // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
      // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
      iconImageOffset: [-24, -24],
      // Смещение слоя с содержимым относительно слоя с картинкой.
      iconContentOffset: [15, 15],
      // Макет содержимого.
      iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
    });

  myMap.geoObjects
    .add(myPlacemark)
    .add(myPlacemarkWithContent);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Примеры. Задание собственного изображения для метки</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="icon_customImage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы скопировали пример с относительными путями, поэтому у вас нет картинок для собственных меток; исправила в вашем ответе

Comment: @Reni Благодарю!